# Как в PHP отключить любые реакции на ошибки

Tags: php, report, exception-handler

Хочу самостоятельно отобразить информацию об ошибке пользователю, но при срабатывании таймаута получаю обновление страницы, все стирается:

```
This page isn’t working ..SITE_NAME.. is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

при этом пробовал:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Обобщая- есть отрисованная страница, скрипт долго не может подключиться к удаленному серверу, хочу вывести окошко "Ошибка подключения к серверу" со своими стилями, **не затирая уже отображенную информацию**. Сейчас срабатывает класс обработки ошибок errorHandler и производится вывод с определенной детализацией в окно контента. По таймауту может не отработать как локальный скрипт, так и не ответить удаленный сервер, поэтому не хочу выносить конкретное оформление в errorHandler.

Comment: Конкретный вопрос - как подавить ошибку : "Failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known."   Я хочу вывести информацию для пользователя а не саму ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, "мешали" ошибки при соединении с серверами. Нашел в интернете решение:

```
function isSiteAvailible($url) {
// Проверка правильности URL
  if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
    return false;
  }

  // Инициализация cURL
  $curlInit = curl_init($url);

  // Установка параметров запроса
  curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
  curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
  curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
  curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

  // Получение ответа
  $response = curl_exec($curlInit);

  // закрываем CURL
  curl_close($curlInit);

  return $response ? true : false;
}
```